# "ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor" on WebLogic Version 12.2.1.1 and Later (Doc ID 2526226.1)

Tags: java, weblogic

I am trying to deploy my legacy application in **web-logic 12c** but problem is every time its showing exception like > **"ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor**,Basically this issue comes if application not have **asm.jar** but in my application **asm.jar** is there and moreover my application successfully deployed in **web-logic 11**

After lot of research i found below document in that they are saying **WebLogic 12.2.1 infra to WebLogic 12.2.1.3 infra, the class org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitorbelow can NOT be found when starting the server with customer's application deployed.** Please some one guide me how can i resolve this issue

### Document

https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2526226_1.html#FIX

### Deployment issue

```
<Dec 6, 2019 5:58:46,064 AM GMT> <Error> <HTTP> <WL-101216> <Servlet: "JerseyRESTService" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "CDMWeb.war".
A MultiException has 1 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor

    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.justCreate(Utilities.java:1085)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.create(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:978)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1082)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.createAndInitialize(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1074)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.createApplication(ApplicationHandler.java:385)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.verizon.application.Application.<init>(Application.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.findClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:398)
    at com.oracle.classloader.PolicyClassLoader.loadClass(PolicyClassLoader.java:371)
    at com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:55)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:79)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

Comment: Did you try the solution as mentioned in that document?

Comment: No did not because for opening that document they are asking support identifier

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the asm.jar to your Applications's WEB-INF/lib directory. From the error it's clear that JVM not able to locate the class, hence java.lang.ClassNotFoundException